# maximum value of for loop in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql

I'd like to know, what is the maximum value in a [for loop statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1536)?
Is the datatype `NUMBER`?

```
BEGIN
  -- Bounds are numeric literals:
  FOR j IN 1..5000 LOOP
    NULL;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I will need up to 3x10^14

Comment: got result adding '3x10^14' value in loop ?

Comment: I'd be interested to know why you'd want a loop that iterated 300 trillion times.  That strikes me as rather... inefficient.

Comment: At the end i will only loop something like 100k at ones. Next time i will start at last value and repeat it. So after some time it could be reach up to this number. For something like hexadecimal serialnumbers.

Comment: What is your real problem you're solving ?

Comment: As I wrote, I need unique hexadecimal numbers in sequence, but with gaps. So, now I have to use a sequence and alter the start value each time before using. Thats also fine. I only looked for an alternative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1536), the lower and upper bounds of a `for` expression are stored in a temporary `pls_integer` variable. According to [`pls_integer`'s documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/datatypes.htm#i10726), it can hold values from -2147483648 to 2147483647, represented in 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

You can give yourself some more room with regards to the upper bound on the loop iterator.  For example if you have a loop like this:

```
declare
  lower_bound number := 2147483640;
  upper_bound number := 2147483650; -- <==Exceeds PLS_INTEGER max value
begin
  for i in lower_bound..upper_bound
  loop
    ... do something with i ...
  end loop;
end;
```

that encounters an `ORA-01426: numeric overflow` error you can rewrite your loop like this:

```
declare
  lower_bound number := 2147483640;
  upper_bound number := 2147483650;
  i number;
begin
  for j in 0 .. upper_bound-lower_bound
  loop
    i := j + lower_bound;

    ... do something with i ...
  end loop;
end;
```

In the above code, I've changed the loop iterator from `i` to `j`, changed the loop bounds to always iterate from zero to the number of iterations required, and added a new local variable `i` to be used by your original code.  Finally adding `i := j + lower_bound;` as the first statement inside the loop ensures that your code sees `i` the way it expects.

Now as long as you aren't iterating 2,147,483,647 times you should be good.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, why you may needed this much bigger loop.

may be you can try this

Thanks,
Thangamani Eraniyan

```
BEGIN
    FOR j IN 3 LOOP
    begin
        FOR K IN 10 LOOP
            begin
            for L in 14 loop
                Null /* you can try your code here */
            End Loop;
        End Loop;
    END LOOP;
END;
```